# Tornado multiple IOLoop in multithreads

Tags: python, multithreading, tornado

I am trying to run multiple IOLoop in multiple threads and I am wondering how the IOLoop actually works.

```
class WebThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, name='WebThread')

    def run(self):
        curdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

        application = Application() #Very simple tornado.web.Application
        http_server_api = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
        http_server_api.listen(8888)

        logging.info('Starting application')

        #tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance() is singleton, not for thread, right?

        ioloop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop()
        ioloop.make_current()
        ioloop.start()
```

According to the doc, I can not use IOLoop.instance() since it's a singleton and I am working in a thread. So I created my own IOLoop. But this piece of code listens on the port 8888 but can not render any web page. I am wondering is there anything missed, or do I need to tie the http_server to the IOLoop in some way?

Also, I find that removing the last 3 lines and substitute with `tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start` works perfectly for single thread. But what's the difference between the singleton and self created IOLoop?

I am new to Tornado and any answers are welcomed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In general you should use IOLoop.current as the default when constructing an asynchronous object, and use IOLoop.instance when you mean to communicate to the main thread from a different one.

[`IOLoop.current`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current) without params returns **already created ioloop of  thread** or it calls `IOLoop.instance()`. And HTTPServer (actually in TCPServer) use IOLoop.current to interact with ioloop, so the only thing you should change is to create ioloop before HTTPServer e.g.

```
class WebThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, name='WebThread')

    def run(self):
        curdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

        ioloop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop()

        application = Application() #Very simple tornado.web.Application
        http_server_api = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
        http_server_api.listen(8888)

        logging.info('Starting application')

        ioloop.start()
```

Also I've removed `IOLoop.make_current`, since it's redundant - `IOLoop()` sets self as a current.

---

Code above will work, but only with one thread, because reuse_port is not enabled by default. You will end up with:

```
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

You can enable this with

```
    http_server_api.bind(port=8888, reuse_port=True)
    http_server_api.start()
```

instead of `http_server_api.listen(8888)`

Comment: This is awesome answer, thanks. I didn't know that http_server is interacting with the current IOLoop. Thanks so mush for the explanation.